# Gremlin query: how to specify sort order in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am using AWS Neptune.

I want to perform a simple gremlin query that returns vertices sorted in decreasing order by a property named "timestamp".

I can do this using the gremlin console:

gremlin> g.V().has('timestamp').order().by('timestamp', desc).fold()

But when I use this same statement from my nodejs application, I get the error "ReferenceError: desc is not defined".  I am not surprised by the error, since I have not defined "desc".

My question:  how do I pass the sort order in the gremlin query?

Am I missing an import?

I tried passing in the string 'desc' -- that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just missing an import - in [3.3.3](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.3.3/gremlin-javascript/src/main/javascript/gremlin-javascript/lib/process/traversal.js#L263):

```
const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const order = gremlin.process.order;
```

You can read more about it [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/reference/#_static_enums_and_methods_3). Note that 3.3.4 which is not yet released officially will have support for `desc` and `asc` as opposed to `decr` and `incr`.